# How to get the name field value of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a MenuTable model, and I want to use the **name** field in the message of `validate_pressence_of` but instead the value of name field, I got the name of the model

code:

```
class MenuTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :type, :if => lambda {(field.blank?)}, :message => "Error in " + self.name
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all else fails, you can always do a custom-ish validation like this:

```
validate :type_presence_with_message

def type_presence_with_message
  return unless field.blank?

  if type.blank?
    errors.add(:type, "Error in #{name}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#app/models/menu_table.rb
class MenuTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :type, presence: { message: "cannot be blank" }, if: "field.blank?"
end
```

<s>According to Rails docs, you can call the [local `%{value}` variable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion) to customize your error messages with *that* specific field.</s> How can a value exist if its presence is required? My bad, sorry.

[You can also pass a string](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-string-with-if-and-unless) to your `if` logic (looks better IMO).

---

I know this doesn't fix your problem (you want to call another model attribute).

So I did some testing, and found some interesting ideas...

Firstly, the `validates` method seems to *only* pass the attribute in question:

[image]

It seems to use [error message interpolation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation) to give you a set of 3 (or 4) objects to call:

> - %{model}
> - %{attribute}
> - %{value}
> - %{count} (only in numerical instances)

This means that if you want to access other values from the object, you'll have to use a way which is going to grant access to the current model instance values; `@Sergio Tulentsev`'s answer does that well, but I wanted to find a way to use in-line `validates`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21563109/1143732) explains well:

> the validation is scoped to the Class and not the object you are validating

This means you'll have to use `@Sergio Tulentsev`'s answer to create a custom validation (which is scoped onto the object).

Comment: Yeah the problem is by using the name attribute. Instead the value of **name field**, I am getting the name of the class/model. So I created a method and `self.name` / `"#{name}"` is now working.

Comment: Was this in a custom validator?